# How to run the Apex Scheduler in salesforce?

Tags: batch

please give me the one example of batchapex schedular program.how to run the schedule jobs in salesforce .please give one example of that above scenario.give some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In this code i am scheduling apex Code execution after 2 minutes, in the execute method you have to define that code which you want to execute at specific time, we use this method System.schedule(JobName, ScheduleTime, current_class_object) for scheduling execute method. system.abortJob(id) this method is used for abort this job from cronTrigger object, if this jobNamed process is already executed.

```
public class sceduleUpdate implements schedulable{                      

        public void Updateprice(){

            sceduleUpdate su = new SceduleUpdate();

                string day = string.valueOf(system.now().day());
                String month = string.valueOf(system.now().month());
                String hour = string.valueOf(system.now().hour());
                String minute = string.valueOf(system.now().addminutes(2).minute() );
                String second = string.valueOf(system.now().second());
                String year = string.valueOf(system.now().year());  

                String JobName = 'UpdateThreshold';
                String strSchedule = second +' ' + minute+' '+ hour +' '+ day+' '+month+' ?'+' '+ year;
                if([select id from CronJobDetail where name =:jobName].size() > 0){

                    CronJobDetail sb = [select id from CronJobDetail where name =:jobName];
                    CronTrigger Ct = [select id from CronTrigger where CronJobDetailId =:sb.id];
                    system.abortJob(Ct.id);

                }
            system.debug('this  is current time '+system.now());    
            System.schedule(JobName, strSchedule, su);

        }   

        public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){

            system.debug('this is scheduled time '+system.now());

            batchclass btch_hndl = new Batchclass();
            Database.executeBatch(btch_hndl,2);  

        }


    }

//--------- Run from Anonymous window using this code

sceduleUpdate obj = new sceduleUpdate();  
obj.Updateprice();
```

//---- Batch Apex Class

```
public class Batchclass implements Database.Batchable<book__c> {

   public Iterable<book__c> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

           system.debug('Start Executed');
           List<book__c> bk = [Select name,author__c,price__c,domain__c from book__c];
           system.debug('Book Records '+ bk);
           return bk;      
   }

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, LIST<book__c> books){
           system.debug('Execute executed');

           for(book__c b : books){
             b.price__c += 50;
           }

          update books;
          system.debug('updated record '+books);   

   }

  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

          system.debug('Finish Executed');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this    :Adding a Class that Implements the Schedulable Interface:

```
global class MySchedulableClass implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];
System.debug(ct.CronExpression);
System.debug(ct.TimesTriggered);

contact c=new contact();
c.lastname='test';
c.firstname='test';
insert c;

}
}
```

Scheduling and Monitoring Scheduled Jobs
Now that you’ve seen how to create and test a schedulable class, let’s take a look at how to schedule the class using the user interface.
You’ll also learn how to view the list of scheduled jobs in your organization.

1. Click Apex Classes to go back to the Apex Classes page.
2. Click Schedule Apex.
3. For the job name, enter TestSchedulingApexFromTheUI.
4. Click the lookup button next to Apex class and enter * for the search term to get a list of all classes that can be scheduled. In the
   search results, click MySchedulableClass.
5. Select Weekly or Monthly for the frequency and set the frequency desired.
6. Select the start and end dates, and a preferred start time.
   The schedule of a scheduled Apex job is relative to the user’s time zone.
   61
   Part 3: Apex in Context Scheduling and Monitoring Scheduled Jobs
7. Click Save.
8. To go to the Schedule Jobs page, from Setup, click Monitoring > Scheduled Jobs or Jobs > Scheduled Jobs.
   You’ll see that your job is now listed in the job queue.
9. Click Manage next to the job’s name.
   The page displays more details about the job, including its execution schedule.